# on focus display just one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, this

I have a simple problem:

I have a **form**:

```
<form>
    <textarea type="text" name="comment_text" class="comment-input"></textarea>
    <div class="remaining"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="button comment-button" />
</form>
```

Now when the **textarea** (.comment-text) **is focused I want the submit button** (.comment-button) **to be displayed using jQuery**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //display the comment button when the comment textarea is focused
    $('.comment-input').focus(function() {
        $('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

This works fine. **The problem** is that I have the **form in a foreach loop and when I focus one textarea all the buttons get selected**. So I was **trying to do it with the 'this' keyword** something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       //display the comment button when the comment textarea is focused
        $('.comment-input').focus(function() {
            $(this).find('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
```

But that **did not work**. After trying things out for way too long now, I just decided that I do not speak sufficient jQuery to master this simple task and turned to somebody in the know for help!
**Thank you** in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the button is a sibling element of the textarea

```
$(this).siblings('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` will try to find a child element in the textarea so it will never find your button:

you can use `siblings`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       //display the comment button when the comment textarea is focused
        $('.comment-input').focus(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Arun P Johny, was as correct, as you are while being a little bit faster, so I will go with his answer. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Sure dude, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Sibling is the solution for this problem , but no more will works if you wrap the submit button in any wrapper(div or span) .

This will work safer -

```
$(this).closest("form").find('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Arun P Johny, was as correct, as you are while being a little bit faster, so I will go with his answer. But thank you anyway!

Comment: not a issue , discussion is the key of learning .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

There are others ways to get the correct element other than these 3 answers,

```
$(this).parent().find('.comment-button').fadeIn(800);
```

or

```
$(this).next().next().fadeIn(800);
```

or

```
$(this).nextUntil('.comment-button').next().fadeIn(800);
```